# Should I use Mac for testing iPhone or is Windows enough?

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, selendroid, testautomationfx

I managed to control my android device with both 'ADB' and 'Appium' on windows system.

Question is : Can I do the same for iPhone ? as i heard that it can't be done in windows platform and it isn't clear on net.
Also wanted to know if the iPhone sdk having tools like ADB 'command line tool' to do some things like make phone call , or press , or swipe ..
I trigger all of that with python scripts.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone automation testing with the help of appium, **you must need Mac machine**.For iOS app testing using appium, the primary requirement is XCode which comes with only iOS Operating System which you can get only on MacBook/MacMini.

There is no tool like ADB for iOS. Whatever command you want to send to the device, all those needs to be sent through appium driver only. You can check the appium driver, there are lot of in built methods like hiding keyboard or launching app or opening notifications panel etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but lets say i have a MAC machine as interface for using iphoneSDK && XCode , now question is if my testing environment is in windows machine , how should i connect these things together ? as i am not planning to port my test environment to MAC of course !